# How to resolve squiggly lines in HTML files after importing Bootstrap to Angular project?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

After creating Angular project using command, `ng new order` and `cd order`, I executed following command to bring Bootstrap in.

```
npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

After that I updated `angular.json` and now it looks like this. I only edited `scripts` and `styles` arrays:

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "order": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/order",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "order:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "order:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "order:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "order:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "order:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "order"
}
```

After that, in `app.component.html` I paste some navbar html from bootstrap's site. I have following problem:

[image]

After I do `ng serve -o` it renders fine, Bootstrap's styles are there. But the problem is that I cannot do CTRL+space command to have Visual Studio make code completion or suggestion about possible Bootstrap's CSS classes. Somehow the html file doesn't "see" Bootstrap, even tho Angular app do see it.

I cannot resolve those squiggly lines! Any ideas how to fix this?

UPDATE

Below is the tooltip with message.

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, this is my first Angular project, I just want Bootstrap in. I thought that for some reason, jQuery is also required by Bootstrap.

Comment: Do you have any plugins that would cause this? I personally haven't seen this before, except with something like a typo plugin.

Comment: @Eyeslandic I have tried that on a new separate project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7_qowewl2w (2:09). Exactly with command you suggested. Same squiggly lines. I tried that approach first.

Comment: @Phix I don't know, I installed few of them like sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate, ecmel.vscode-html-css few more.

Comment: Is there a tooltip that shows what the issue is with the offending lines when you hover?

Comment: @Phix Yes, I updated post. Thank you!

Comment: I could be wrong here, and my experience isn't everyone's, but I presume that's due to some setting or plugin. VSCode hasn't given me that error ever.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I just pulled this project shorturl.at/ruCQ6 (git repo is at the bottom). Opened with VSCode and again those lines. Any suggestion what to do in VSC or just to reinstall it?

Comment: You'll need to check your settings and installed plugins to see if there's something that would cause that, quick search shows [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/posts/6-awesome-css-extensions-for-vs-code) but there are others. The repo is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what's happening with VSC. I deleted all installed extensions and plugins. Imported project again, same lines appear. Reinstalled it, again same issue. Installed only plugins which Phix proposed, again lines are showing. Maybe there's some config/setting json file in VSCode, but I haven't any idea what it might be. Tried finally with WebStrom, I do have code completion working fine with Bootstrap's CSS classes. Wasted 6h...